# Multiple resumable file download using wget or other command line download tool?

Tags: downloads, wget, download-manager

I know about `wget -c` option to allow resuming resumable download, but can I do multiple resumable download with wget or another command line tool?

Comment: What is "multiple resumable download" supposed to mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this ?

For example you want to download multiple files (which are unknown) from an homepage :

> wget -rvi * http://homepage.com

v is for verbose, r is for recursive and i is for file with following feature/attribute - here feature/attribute is: * for arbitrary files.

First to say : not every domain is allowing wget.

Second to say : if you want any files, you could download some traps too ...

Here is little overview of else commands to work with :

https://superuser.com/questions/261154/how-do-i-download-a-file-using-the-command-line

Somebody told me that scp would be safer and perform more stable downloads than wget.

Comment: `scp` requires SSH to be set up though.

Answer (score 4):

Aria2 is the best and most powerful command line download tool. It can do everything wget can and much more.

http://aria2.sourceforge.net

Aria2 is also used as a plugin with uGet so one can use the power of aria2 with the user-friendly GUI of uGet.

http://uGetdm.com